# Solve nonlinear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to solve the following ODE:
$$
f'(t) + \gamma\left[ r+\frac{\sigma^{-2}B^2}{2(1-\gamma)} \right]f(t)+(1-\gamma)e^{-\frac{\rho t}{1-\gamma}}\left( f(t) \right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}} = 0,
$$
$$
f(T) = e^{-\rho T},
$$
where all the letters except $f$ and $t$ can be regarded as constant. Any solution or hint will be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a Bernouilli equation, you could use $z=f^{\frac{-1}{\gamma -1}}$ to get a linear equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f'(t) + \gamma\left[ r+\frac{\sigma^{-2}B^2}{2(1-\gamma)} \right]f(t)+(1-\gamma)e^{-\frac{\rho t}{1-\gamma}}\left( f(t) \right)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}} = 0,
$$
$$
f(T) = e^{-\rho T},
$$

This ODE can be re-written as
$$f'(t)+af(t)+b e^{-ct} f^q=0=f^{-q}f'+a f^{1-q}=-be^{-ct}$$
which is a Bernoulli IDE as pointed out in the comment above.
Take $f^{1-q}=z \implies (1-q) f^{-q} f'=z'$, then
$$\frac{z'}{1-q}+az=-be^{-ct} \implies z'+(1-q)az=-b(1-q)e^{-ct}$$
This is linear ODE with integrating factor as $I=e^{(1-q)at}$.
Then $$z=f^q= e^{-(1-q)at} \int e^{(1-q)at} (-b(1-q)e^{-ct}) dt+D e^{-(1-q)at}$$
$$\implies f(t)=\left(\frac{-b(1-q)}{a-aq-c} e^{-ct}+ D e^{(q-1)at}\right)^{1/q}.$$